# Jython SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, web, jython

I want to develop a SOAP web service application by using jython. Jython will create the server side of the applciation and call methods from another java application. In python soaplib module realized all the things I want to do. For hours I am searching on the internet but I have not found any documentation. Only one thing that I found is wso/wsf api but it does not have enough documentation.

You can have any idea for my problem? Which module should I use?

Comment: Jython has access to Java Libraries. Why dont't you do it using Java and access it through Jython. Also, did you check [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices) from the Python website containing list of libraries to develop Web services? Maybe you can find what you are looking for there.

Answer (score 1):

[Pyramid 1.1 runs well on Jython](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.1-branch/narr/install.html#installing-pyramid-on-jython). There are plugins for various RPC methods including JSON-RPC and [SOAP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_soap/0.1). Overall I've been pretty happy with Jython + Pyramid as a way to handle RPC for java libs without writing everything in Java.